# Simple WYSIWYG not working, reason unknown

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

My wysiwyg stopped working and I can't find what's causing the problem, here is a fiddle showing the basic (not working) behavior..

http://jsfiddle.net/z5LL2n6n/

The basic code is:

```
<div class="icon-italic" onclick="document.execCommand('italic',null,false);">ITALIC</div>
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Btw I'm on chrome 41.0.2272.118

Comment: This site is not FreeProgramming.com.  If you have a question, ask it. "Not working" is not a question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Malvolio, If I knew exactly what to ask, I would ask google.. in this case the best I could do is "reason unknown", sorry.

Comment: Don't take it personal Raphael.  This site is full of people who don't know how to professionally communicate.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not quite sure how I would have worded the question either... The problem wasn't immediately obvious even if you [read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand). It's not like it required writing code. Sometimes we just need a little pair programming to squash these bugs :)

Comment: In any bug report, you need to record three things: what you did, what you wanted to see, and what you saw.  Without those things, any attempt to respond to the bug is guesswork.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try change the click elements to be `button` instead of `div`. When you click the div, it deselects the text so there's nothing to highlight.

http://jsfiddle.net/z5LL2n6n/1/

```
<button class="icon-bold" onclick="document.execCommand('bold',null,false);">BOLD</button>
<button class="icon-italic" onclick="document.execCommand('italic',null,false);">ITALIC</button>
```